# make temporal link with PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, download

I won make VIP download script that not show main download link and make temporal link with fake address for downloads.
I use below class but with this , not show file size and download can't be resume.

```
class hidden_download{

switch ($ext) { 
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break; 
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break; 
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break; 
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break; 
  case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break; 
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break; 
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break; 
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break; 
  case "jpeg": 
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break; 
  default: $ctype="application/force-download"; 
} 

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
header("Content-Type: $ctype"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($download_url)."\";" ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize); 
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile( $download_url ); ;
}  }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: A class with only a switch statement?? how does that work?

Comment: my question : How can make temporal address with capability resume download and showsize